# Is FileMaker Server required to display a database on a website?

Tags: filemaker

Do you need FileMaker Server (software) to display a database on a website?  Trying to pull data from hosted FileMaker database and have it displayed in real time on an existing page of website.

More specifically does Custom Web Publishing only exist in FileMaker Server and not pro?

Comment: I suggest you join one of the FileMaker-specific forums for this type of questions.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you need FileMaker Server (software) to display a database on a
>   website?

In real time, yes. Otherwise you could export periodically to the web.

> More specifically does Custom Web Publishing only exist in FileMaker
>   Server

Yes.

However, as I already mentioned in a [comment to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021219/sync-filemaker-and-phpmyadmin#comment61601279_37021219), you *can* use the FileMakerPro (client) application to interact directly with a MySQL database.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm actually not working with mySQL anymore instead trying to use a hosted FileMaker database.  That being said, I assume my best option is still Custom Web Publishing.

Comment: "*I assume my best option is still Custom Web Publishing.*" Probably. Hard for me to say with so little to go on. And, as I said, this is totally off topic for Stack Overflow.